# Swift Dictionary append or insert

Tags: swift, dictionary

What is the correct way to add a new element to this type of dictionary (deep dictionary) in Swift 5:

```
var myDictionary : [String : [String : [String]]] = [:]
for (word: String,type: String,sentences: [String]) in collection {
  myDictionary[word] = [type : sentences] // assignment
  // but what if myDictionary[word] already existed? and if type already existed?
  // myDictionary[word, default: [type : sentences]] // ???
}
```

Comment: How about looking up the entry first and if you find it, don't add it again?

Comment: There must be a clever 1-liner out there

Comment: You're probably looking for `Dictionary.init(_:groupingBy:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `default` for dictionary

```
myDictionary[word, default: [:]][type, default:[]] += sentences
```

Answer (score 0):

`myDictionary[word, default: [type : []]][type, default: []] += sentences`